# Unable to call static function inside its own class

Tags: javascript, class, static-functions

How can I call static function inside the class itself? I try self keyword instead of this but I still get error.

```js
class Test {
  static staticFunction() {
    console.log('Inside static function.');
  }
  regularFunction() {
    this.staticFunction();
  }
}

let test = new Test();
test.regularFunction();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference the static function through the class name, like this:

```js
class Test {
  static staticFunction(input) {
    console.log('Inside static function.');
  }
  regularFunction() {
    Test.staticFunction();
  }
}

let test = new Test();
test.regularFunction();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the this reference to access a static function. You should just do staticFunction(input) or even better Test.staticFunction(input).

Answer (score 1):

Can not use 'this'  in static methods or classes